# How can I get the option to install alongside Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Prior Ubuntu Desktop Install alongside Windows Vista failed due to power failure.  During installation and prior to failure, I got to the Installation Type and checked to install alongside Windows.

I am once again trying to install, however when I get to the Installation type, the only choices I have are Replace Windows and Something Else.  I am not ready to replace/remove Windows at this time.  How do I get a clean install with all the Installation Types available?

Comment: If you select "Something Else" is there already a partition formatted as ext4 that is the same size as the Windows Vista partition? If so, you can use it to install Ubuntu, and it'll be just like the alongside choice. I can take you through the few steps to set it up correctly in a answer if you need it.

Comment: I did look in the 'Something Else', but do not recall seeing anything titled as 'ext4'.  Should I try the install again to see what is available?

Comment: Or you can open a application called "Gparted" it will show you a better picture of what is on your drive.

Comment: Okay, so I opened Gparted, but not a clue what I am looking at or for.  But I do not see anything in reference to the 'ext4'.  Is there anyway to post a pic so that you can see what I am looking at?

Comment: You can use "Print Screen" on the keyboard to take a screen shot. You'll have to upload it to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and add a link to you post so I can see it. You don't have enough reputation to just add it to your post.

Comment: Or you can just look at the "File System" Column in Gparted (Below the colored rectangle). It's the second one from the left. If you don't see ext4 in any of the cells then you don't have a Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Okay, the picture link is http://imgur.com/tRVherw

Comment: Okay that's interesting. Does clicking the red exclamation point circle thing tell you information. That's usually not a good sign.

Comment: Yes, information is there...  ugh!  For sda2, pic is http://imgur.com/yzGiNxS  for sda3, pic is http://imgur.com/Rk1NCgy

Comment: Ok yeah, you need to log into Windows and run a disk check on both of those drives. Ubuntu isn't going to let you use the install alongside option until you do this. Hopefully, Windows is working. it sounds like it powered off while resizing those partitions.

Comment: First off, I apologize, thank you so much for your help on this!  I will log into Windows and run the disk checks.  I will let you know what happens.  Thank you again.

Comment: After completing the disk check on both drives, I was able to install without issue.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- boot into windows, right click my computer and select manage. Under disk management remove all the Linux partitions being very careful not to remove the windows partition.
- Remove the partitions to the point where windows describes it as un-allocated space.

** Verify you can still boot to windows otherwise grub won't install properly. if you can't boot windows, boot into recovery mode with a windows disk and at the command line type `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.

Once you get to the point where windows boots, you can re install Linux.